# logical expression in bash

Tags: bash, scripting

The purpose of the script is go over file contains list of directory names and append to other file directory names that are not exist in.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="list.txt"
2nd_file="2nd_list.txt"
for f in $FILES
do
    # if  backup dir exists, read next dir
if [ /bin/grep -q $f $2nd_file ]
then
    echo "Skiping $f file..."
    continue  # read next file
fi
    # we are hear means no file exists
    echo "$f" >>$2nd_file
done
```

I getting errors in if expression.

I understood what your answers about and changed the script :

```
 #!/bin/bash
 FILES="list.txt"
 2nd_file="2nd_list.txt"
 for f in $FILES
 do
        # if  backup dir exists, read next dir
 /bin/grep -q $f $2nd_file
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then
    echo "Skiping $f file..."
    continue  # read next file
fi
    # we are hear means no dir exists
     echo "$f" >>$2nd_file
done
```

But now a small problem that script doesn't read directory names from FILES

Output is :

```
 Skiping list.txt file...
```

Comment: You probably meant `>>$2nd_file` and not `>>2nd_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your if expression should be:

```
if  /bin/grep -q $f $2nd_file
```

without square brackets

**EDITED as you edited your post:**

Your script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="list.txt"
2nd_file="2nd_list.txt"
for f in $(cat $FILES) # see the modification
do
    # if  backup dir exists, read next dir
if /bin/grep -q $f $2nd_file # see the modification
then
    echo "Skiping $f file..."
    continue  # read next file
fi
    # we are hear means no file exists
    echo "$f" >>$2nd_file
done
```

The modifications I've made are:

- in the "for": you need the content of $FILE archive, not the string "list.txt" (the value of $FILES variable) so you have to dump those contents with `cat` or with a "<" (ie: `while read f; do ... ; done < $FILES`)
- in the if statement: you have to evaluate a command. The command is you grep. If grep returns 0 then your "if" stuff will be done; any other return value will skip your if statement. (that's like your useless check of the return status but more efficient)

Answer (score 1):

`[` is a command. If you're trying to use `grep` as the command, then don't use `[`.

Comment: Thank you , but if I want to check if result of grep is 0 or 1 like     if /bin/grep -q $f $2nd_file == 1 ?